# Import a local JSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to have my initialization code import a JSON file, I don't know if I'm not looking up my question properly but I can't find a solution. Ideally, it would run completely offline. Right now I don't have any additional JavaScript library, so keeping it vanilla would be a plus.

**Full context:** I'm trying to make a game that runs on JavaScript (using an HTML to display everything), using nothing but local files so it can run offline. The JSON files would be used to import data like maps, characters, equipment, skills, and maybe plain text to make translating easier. It's for the latter purpose that I want to import the JSON files using JavaScript, so I can import the right file based on the language picked.

I'm fairly new to JavaScript.

Comment: JSON is a subset of a JavaScript object. You can therefore just define it in any JavaScript file you are using (see the answers). You would benefit however if you put your code on a local webserver which you can then access via `http://localhost`. You can then access all files you are serving e.g. via XHR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options you have:

1. Include the JSON within your javascript code itself.
2. Request the file via an AJAX call.

Comment: An AJAX call looks like it would prevent my project from being fully offline. Can you talk me through including the JSON within my code?

Comment: You can make AJAX offline as well, assuming you are running a local HTTP server. Just call to localhost. If you are not even running a local server. I would suggest option 1.

Comment: By the first option, do you mean simply writing the JSON as a JavaScript object? If that's the case, I might as well import a simple JS file whose only purpose is to declare the object, based on the (human) language I want to apply.

Comment: Yes, if that works for you, you can simply just do that. (You can accept my answer btw if it helped)

Answer (score 0):

According to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/laurenancona/bd560948d71054e3d1477e43c4d48cb6) on Github, you can just import the json file just like a .js file.
The JSON needs to be an object as shown in the example below.

This is the example code I just tried:
HTML / JS:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file.json"></script>
    <script>
        console.log(data);
    </script>
```

JSON:

```
      data = {
             "id": 5,
             "name": "Marconymous",
             "origin": "Switzerland"
          }
```

Comment: That would be reading the .json file as a .js file. Once again I'm fairly new, but I know that a JSON typically starts with an {. Even Visual Studio Code returns a problem if you try starting the file's contents with "data = {".

Comment: I tried changing the code to:
`{
  "data" : {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Marconymous",
    "origin": "Switzerland"
  }
}`
VSC doesn't see an error, but now in Chrome I get an error so that wont work.

Comment: I got the same thing. I think it's because the HTML script tag reads the file in JavaScript. So this second syntax is correct for a JSON, but not for a script element.

Comment: Most likely yes.

Answer (score 0):

Easy as using type="module" for script, which allows the use of import.

index.html

```html
<script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
```

script.js

```js
import jsonData from './json-file.json' assert {type : 'json'};

console.log(jsonData);
```

json-file.json

```json
{
  "name" : "John",
  "age" : 26,
  "height" : 1.78
}
```